# Doctype changing

Tags: doctype

In the sourcecode, I have the doctype as `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

But in the browser, while viewing sourcecode('View SourceCode' option), I am finding doctype as `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Why is it so? Any problems with this?

Answer (score 0):

Those DOCTYPEs are definitely different, and in some browsers will trigger different behaviour. However, it's impossible for that to change on the fly. Are you absolutely sure that the changes you make to that document are being reflected on what you see in the website?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Firefox and Chrome always show `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the inspector and the page source no matter what doctype you set.</strike>

* This browser bug has been patched.

Comment: Huh? No! What gave you that idea? They still handle long doctypes the way they used to; e.g. they still use the old "almost standards" mode if you have `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Comment: They just SHOW the new doctype in the inspector!

Comment: Not on my machine they don't. And I've tested ALL the browsers: Chrome AND Firefox.